Ray casting from orthogonal camera
Using Godot 4.3, I’m building a top down game with an orthogonal camera. I am trying to detect a tile when the mouse hovers over it and having issues with the detection.
The tile is an Area3D node with a 3DCollisionShape:

The tiles display their position (rounded).
The overhead camera scene is a CharacterBody3D node with a Camera3D and RayCast3D nodes (the collision shape is disabled):

The All nodes are at default position and rotation other than RayCastingCamera where rotation.X = -90 so it points downward.
The GUI scene (main) is a Node3D with the overhead camera positioned at (0,8,0). The tiles are added via code at positions (x,0,z):

Overhead camera script:
public partial class OverheadCameraBody : CharacterBody3D
{
    private RayCast3D downwardRay;
    private Camera3D rayCastingCamera;
    private GodotObject detectedCollider = null;

    public override void _Ready()
    {
        rayCastingCamera = GetNode<Camera3D>("RayCastingCamera");
        downwardRay = rayCastingCamera.GetNode<RayCast3D>("DownwardRay");
    }

    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        detectedCollider = CastMouseRay();  
    }
    
    public override void _Input(InputEvent @event)
    {
        if (Input.IsActionPressed("selection"))
        {
            if (detectedCollider != null)
            {
                GD.Print("Selected object is: " + detectedCollider.ToString());
            } else {
                GD.Print("No collider detected");
        }
    }

    private GodotObject CastMouseRay() {
        // Getting the mouse position on the viewport
        Vector2 mousePosition = GetViewport().GetMousePosition();
        // Transalting the mouse position to world position and assigning to camera target
        downwardRay.TargetPosition = rayCastingCamera.ProjectPosition(mousePosition, Position.Y + 20.0f);
        downwardRay.ForceRaycastUpdate();
        return downwardRay.GetCollider();
    }
}

The ray’s position and target are where I expect them, and align with the position of the tiles, but the tile is not detected (pointing at the upper left tile and clicking):


I am closing this issue. The code was written for a camera in perspective mode, and doesn't work in orthogonal mode.
